# Powerbuilder 12 Enterprise - I can't get the program I made to run on another computer

Tags: powerbuilder

Previous used PB 9, PC Client worked fine - got all the dll's copied in Sybase. It was a simplified routine.

We've upgraded to PB 12 and now that procedure is all mess up. I'm trying this on a Win 7 machine but will have to do this for XP eventually.

1. I run the runtime manager with as many things checked as possible
2. I select PB Components (as opposed to .NET)
   It yields PBCLTRT120.msi

This file doesn't run. First it was PBVM120 not registering. So a copied it. 
Next it was a java script (I don't use Java), so I unchecked it.
Now I get a Native.dll file not found in cabinet. I ignore that.
Next MSVCR12.dll not found.

Basically I looked like something didn't install properly. But my source program on my computer works. But my runtime file doesn't seem to successfully convey the neccesary file.

PB9 has a number of files that I had to manually copy. Even the runtime file didn't catch everything. Any suggestions?

John

Answer (score 2):

Call me paranoid (you're not paranoid if they're *really* out to get you), but I've never trusted the Runtime Packager, which is what I'm guessing you're trying to use now. I go into the Application Techniques manual (if you haven't installed them locally, [Sybase keeps them online](http://sybooks.sybase.com)), look up the files I need for my specific application (e.g. I need rich text files, I don't need web services) in a chapter near the back, and separate those files out for inclusion in an installation package that includes my application executables. To complete the paranoia, I load my application (my executables, the PB run times) into a fresh virtual machine and test it from there. I will roll back the changes and test the installation package in the re-fresh VM as well.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: I second the 'self-packaging'.

Comment: Solved:
The Win 7 machine is 64 bit. While Vista has been tested Sybase does not support it. When it does work it's 'magic'. I tried it on XP 32 and it runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by installing the evaluation version of PB12 on the computer. It's my standard for the network. Very sloppy that the runtime packager doesn't work as advertised.